# Unable to connect USARSim enviroment from ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
**I have USARSim running on windows7 on a desktop and P3AT is loaded using Iridium.
In my laptop I have ROS installed and through a LAN wire I try to connect to both machines. I type follow commands in my laptop which are given below:

1.roscore

2.roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch**
Then following error comes------>

root@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/usarsim_inf# roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch

... logging to /root/.ros/log/e8177c52-2a5e-11e3-8c4e-3c970e099562/roslaunch-ubuntu-16625.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:50443/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro
- /rosversion
- /usarsim/hostname
- /usarsim/odomSensor
- /usarsim/port
- /usarsim/robotType
- /usarsim/startPosition

NODES
/
RosSim (usarsim_inf/usarsim_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found

process[RosSim-1]: started with pid [16645]

**[ERROR] [1380608092.814006960]: connect**

**[ERROR] [1380608092.814131851]: can't open socket to localhost port 3000**

**[ERROR] [1380608092.814522262]: Error from usarsimInf, exiting**

usarsim_node: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:62: boost::recursive_mutex::~recursive_mutex(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.

[RosSim-1] process has died [pid 16645, exit code -6, cmd /root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/usarsim_inf/bin/usarsim_node __name:=RosSim __log:=/root/.ros/log/e8177c52-2a5e-11e3-8c4e-3c970e099562/RosSim-1.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/e8177c52-2a5e-11e3-8c4e-3c970e099562/RosSim-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...

... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

root@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/usarsim_inf#

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85311/unable-to-connect-usarsim-enviroment-from-ros/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-02**:
two additional comments:

1. the P3AT loaded with Iridium will be controlled by Iridium and will be unaffected by USARSimRos. In other words: there is no need to use Iridium if you are going to use USARSim
2. you can run the command as a normal user, there is no need to run it as root

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-02**:
I am following this paper "USARSIM/ROS: A COMBINED FRAMEWORK FOR ROBOTIC CONTROL AND
SIMULATION" by Stephen. Here he mentioned the steps; so even if we use ROS then somehow the robot must be placed in the environment of USARSim by something which is Iridium. So after loading teleop package from ROS can control the robot.
Have you tried differently?

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-02**:
Also I follow the same paper. The robot is spawned where specified in the .launch file, there is no need to use Iridium. You can then control the robot sending cmd_vel messages. I think we are going off topic, send me an email at cristiano.nattero AT unige DOT it, ok?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-02**:
ok kr1zz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the solution is here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/85786/usarsimlaunch-file-is-there-any-error/?answer=86326#post-id-86326

---

Originally posted by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) with karma: 116 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1